# Error:property 'token' does not exist on type' () => any'

Tags: node.js, angular, ionic2

I have created a provider for authentication in ionic2 and Angualr2 for login, which is as follows:

`login provider`

```
@Injectable()
export class Service{
public token : any;
constructor(public http: Http, public storage: Storage){}

    login(credentials){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
    //headers implemented.
    this.http.post('url',credentials, {headers: headers} )
    .subscribe(res=>{
    let data = res.json();
    this.token = data.token // error is shown here. red line on token.
    storage.set('token',data.token)
    resolve(credentials);});
```

Error which is reflected on the token is mentioned in the comment line on the word `token` of `data.token`.

Need Help.

Comment: Is it a typo? `public tken : any;`. I think it should be `public token : any;`

Comment: Your property has a typo:  `public tken`

Comment: sorry it is a typo here..but not in the actual code..updated the question @Abhi

Comment: where is data declared?

Comment: `let data = res.json;` updated it now..@suraj

Comment: `this.http.post('url', {headers: headers}, credentials)` doesnt match the angular http call either..needs to be url,body and reqoptions

Comment: ok, sorry , I made a typo here but in the actual code it is as per the required format, updating it again...

Comment: @suraj any idea on this error?

Comment: are you able to log res?

Comment: I don't have any data in credentials right now, I am designing the frontend, I have to design the frontend for login, only set the servers till now.

Answer (score 2):

You should use type declarations. Based on the error you are using a strict TypeScript configuration. Also by using `async/await` you can produce much more readable code. The issue you are having is either that you do not set `let data: any`, or because you are missing the `;` after the declaration of `data`, in combination with not using `this.storage`, but just `storage`:

```
@Injectable()
export class Service{
    public token : any;

    constructor(public http: Http, public storage: Storage){}

    login async (credentials: any): Promise<any> {
        let data: any = await this.http.post('url',credentials, {
            headers: headers
        }).map(r => r.json()).toPromise();
        this.token = data.token;
        this.storage.set('token', data.token);
        return credentials;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

what is res.json()? is it a function or properties or converting from stringto json

Try

```
json.parse(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

you should import `import { Response } from '@angular/http';` and everything will work fine